# Don't repeat checks on event methods (Bukkit/Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, abstraction

I was reviewing my codebase for a major project of mine and i've noticed that there are over 150 event handlers that all run essentially the same check:

```java
        if (!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player))
            return;
        if (!(event.getEntity() instanceof Player))
            return;

        Player player = (Player) event.getDamager();

        Player victim = (Player) event.getEntity();

        if(!AntigriefManager.canInjure(player, victim)) return;

        if (!EnchantChecks.mainhand(player, this)) return;
```

My question is, can would there be a good way of abstracting this away?

Is it possible to pass those player and victim values to multiple `EntityDamageByEntityEvent` handlers instead of writing them above each one?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask yourself this: why are you registering this check 150 times? From what I see, you're using a static utility anyhow, it doesn't seem to require state from outside of the handler. You could just register it once on startup (maybe in the antigrief plugin/whatever handles that) and not worry about it again

Comment: @Rogue the check is at the top of methods that contain other code - i'm not registering the same check over and over again with nothing above it

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `EventHandler`, specifically `priority` and `ignoreCancelled`.

Right now you have this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onMyEvent(SomeEvent event) {
    //a) A bunch of precheck code
    //b) The actual code you want to run, in several different code bodies
}
```

What you will end up doing is splitting these tasks into two different listeners; one will handle the checks, the other will run whatever it is responsible for. For this, our checks will run on `EventPriority.LOWEST`, because those are run before any other priority. On top of that, if the event is cancelled, we will use `EventHandler#ignoreCancelled` to indicate our code should not be run:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST)
public void onMyPrechecks(SomeEvent event) {
    //a) A bunch of precheck code, for example:
    if (!AntigriefManager.canInjure(player, victim)) {
        //notice we cancel, instead of returning from a method
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}

//Elsewheres, in another class probably:
//priority should never go lower than LOW
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOW, ignoreCancelled = true)
public void onMyEvent(SomeEvent event) {
    //b) The actual code you want to run, e.g.:
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage("running event!");
}
```

Comment: problem is that a lot of methods that i check can't be cancelled, things like death events - and a lot of other events shouldn't be cancelled, just not call my code - is there a workaround or any sort of way to give an event metadata?

Comment: You can implement your own event that fires off of another event, a little unconventional but gives you more flexibility. I would ask if you're really needing to handle these checks in non-cancellable events; things like entity damage would nullify cases of player death for Antigrief, not to mention EnchantChecks. In reality, you can likely get away with one or two events per check for these and retain the functionality you truly desire